# Strato shell_exec(php ...)

Tags: php, html, shell-exec

I'm working with Strato as webhoster. If I want to execute a php-script with a shell_execute directive, which includes php (for example, to run another php-Script or to simply ask for the php-version), I receive the following output:

> 'X-Powered-By: PHP/5.5.38 Content-type: text/html X-Powered-By: PHP/5.5.38 Content-type: text/html X-Powered-By: PHP/5.5.38 Content-type: text/html X-Powered-By: PHP/5.5.38 Content-type: text/html X-Powered-By: PHP/5.5.38 Content-type: text/html X-Powered-By: PHP/5.5.38 Content-type: text/html X-Powered-By: PHP/5.5.38 Content-type: text/html X-Powered-By: PHP/5.5.38 Content-type: text/html X-Powered-By: PHP/5.5.38 Content-type: text/html X-Powered-By: PHP/5.5.38 Content-type: text/html X-Powered-By: PHP/5.5.38 Content-type: text/html X-Powered-By: PHP/5.5.38 Content-type: text/html X-Powered-By: PHP/5.5.38 Content-type: text/html X-Powered-By: PHP/5.5.38 Content-type: text/html X-Powered-By: PHP/5.5.38 Content-type: text/html X-Powered-By: PHP/5.5.38 Content-type: text/html X-Powered-By: PHP/5.5.38 Content-type: text/html X-Powered-By: PHP/5.5.38 Content-type: text/html X-Powered-By: PHP/5.5.38 Content-type: text/html X-Powered-By: PHP/5.5.38 Content-type: text/html X-Powered-By: PHP/5.5.38 Content-type: text/html X-Powered-By: PHP/5.5.38 Content-type: text/html X-Powered-By: PHP/5.5.38 Content-type: text/html X-Powered-By: PHP/5.5.38 Content-type: text/html X-Powered-By: PHP/5.5.38 Content-type: text/html X-Powered-By: PHP/5.5.38 Content-type: text/html X-Powered-By: PHP/5.5.38 Content-type: text/html X-Powered-By: PHP/5.5.38 Content-type: text/html X-Powered-By: PHP/5.5.38 Content-type: text/html X-Powered-By: PHP/5.5.38 Content-type: text/html X-Powered-By: PHP/5.5.38 Content-type: text/html X-Powered-By: PHP/5.5.38 Content-type: text/html X-Powered-By: PHP/5.5.38 Content-type: text/html X-Powered-By: PHP/5.5.38 Content-type: text/html X-Powered-By: PHP/5.5.38 Content-type: text/html X-Powered-By: PHP/5.5.38 Content-type: text/html X-Powered-By: PHP/5.5.38 Content-type: text/html X-Powered-By: PHP/5.5.38 Content-type: text/html X-Powered-By: PHP/5.5.38 Content-type: text/html X-Powered-By: PHP/5.5.38 Content-type: text/html X-Powered-By: PHP/5.5.38 Content-type: text/html X-Powered-By: PHP/5.5.38 Content-type: text/html X-Powered-By: PHP/5.5.38 Content-type: text/html X-Powered-By: PHP/5.5.38 Content-type: text/html X-Powered-By: PHP/5.5.38 Content-type: text/html X-Powered-By: PHP/5.5.38 Content-type: text/html X-Powered-By: PHP/5.5.38 Content-type: text/html X-Powered-By: PHP/5.5.38 Content-type: text/html X-Powered-By: PHP/5.5.38 Content-type: text/html X-Powered-By: PHP/5.5.38 Content-type: text/html X-Powered-By: PHP/5.5.38 Content-type: text/html X-Powered-By: PHP/5.5.38 Content-type: text/html X-Powered-By: PHP/5.5.38 Content-type: text/html X-Powered-By: PHP/5.5.38 Content-type: text/html Warning: shell_exec(): Unable to execute 'php -v' in /path/to/test.php on line 9 '

Has anybody seen this before and has a solution for this problem?